# Existence and Uniqueness of Solutions to First-Order Non-Linear Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I go about proving the uniqueness of an existing solution to a recurrence equation of the form

$$
a_{n+1} - f(n)a_n = 0
$$
?

Is there a theorem related to questions of uniqueness and existence for recurrence relations of a certain type as is the case for ordinary differential equations?

Comment: Solving a recurrence relation is very similar (if not equivalent) to solving a differential equation.  I would also tag differential equations and see if anyone can help you there.

Comment: What is the uniqueness proof for ordinary differential equations?  I think it should be applicable to recurrence relations (as per my previous comment).

Comment: This is a (very simple) homogeneous linear recurrence of the first order, just not with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If the recurrence equation is of the form $$a_{n+1} - f(n)a_n = 0$$ you could easily show that the solution is simply given by $$a_n=c \prod _{i=1}^{n-1} f(i)$$

Comment: Oh! Well that's simple enough to make me feel kind of sheepish :P. Thank you! How, then, now, do I prove that that is the ONLY solution?

Comment: Just write the first terms and substitute. This is how I arrived to this formula. I do not see how, from the definition itself, another solution could exist.